# Is 90% - 95% humidity too much for mint / basil / tomatoes?

Tags: greenhouse, humidity

I just got a new Socker greenhouse from Ikea and have been trying to grow herbs inside of it. I noticed my mint and basil started to grow brown spots and a chopstick I inserted into the soil has this white mould growing on it after 3 days.

The humidity inside the greenhouse is around 90% to 95%. It is too moist inside? The humidity around my apartment ranges around 70% to 80%. Is there any point of me to continue to use my greenhouse to grow anything?

[image]

Comment: If it is in direct sun it will also get too hot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A greenhouse should have roughly 50-70% humidity depending on what you are growing. Yes your humidity is far too high. As far as throwing the thing away I would say no. It is still perfectly usable with a little bit of innovation. If you are interested in a fun project, I would suggest you ventilate your greenhouse.

Here is a video on how to cut holes in [glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_NtTBTGp20):

Then all you need is an old computer fan and a small battery. Mount the fan onto the glass tank, wire it up and BAM SON! You got yourself a usable greenhouse XD courtesy of your own two hands.

Comment: In Hong Kong, our humidity outside of the greenhouse is usually 70 - 85%... so lol... really need to add extra ventilation... but does it serve any actual purpose running a greenhouse like that?

Comment: @williamli Surely, if you need your greenhouse to have lower humidity than your normal regional conditions. Adding proper ventilation could easily achieve a humidity @ or below 70% despite your local climate.